# I'm not able to get my proper documentation and used keywords using robot framework hub

Tags: robotframework, keyword

I have installed rfhub for my robot testsuite in order to get all my keywords documentation
[image]

But i didn't find any of my used keywords in this link [image]
Where can i find it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell rfhub where to look for  your keywords. You have to give it the path to your test suites as an argument. If you want rfhub to look in the current directory you can specify `.`:

```
python -m rfhub .
```

Comment: Same result i didn't get anything :/

Comment: @Emna: are your keyword files actually in the current directory? The point is, you have to give it the path to a .robot file, or to a directory that has .robot files.

Comment: Yeah the directory contains many .robotfiles of my testcases that have declaration of their keywords inside